# Can 802.11ac cards make simultaneous dual band access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

If I have a Wi-Fi card that supports both 2.4GHz and 5GHz, can it make an access point on both frequencies simultaneously?

Comment: The answer almost certainly depends on the hardware, firmware and software. If the card supports it, why not? If the card doesn't support it, you'll have a hard time (but *in principle*, it *probably can* be done).

Comment: The question is how to determine whether hardware supports it or not

Comment: No, the question is "If I have a WiFi card that supports both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz can it make access point on both frequencies simultaneously?". If you are really asking a different question, then please [edit] to make that other question clear.

Comment: It supports either of those frequencies

Comment: Unless the card has 2 radios you can't do it simtonously, most cards, have no need for two radios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Dual-band client cards (WNICs) can use either band as needed, but can only do one band at a time. Dedicated access point (wireless router) hardware boxes have two separate WNICs: one for the 2.4GHz band and one for the 5GHz band.

For example, a mid 2013 or later Retina MacBook Pro uses a single Broadcom 4360 dual-band 802.11a/b/g/n/ac radio. But a 2013 802.11ac AirPort Extreme uses two Broadcom 4360's: one to service the 2.4GHz band in b/g/n mode, and one to service the 5GHz band in a/n/ac mode.

Some WNIC chipset vendors have simultaneous dual-band client cards on their roadmaps, where you could have a 2x2 or 3x3 radio on one band and a 1x1 radio on the other band (all in the same chip/interface), but I don't think any have shipped in products yet as of mid-2015.